# Combine All Ajax Messages thru one Action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a website that has a lot of AJAX forms and as it is now I have to make a new js.erb view for each one of them to just post a message that pretty much says completed but is unique to each action.

Is there a way that I can combine or forward one action to a message action in the controller so I would only need one view to handle all the JavaScript messages

Here is what I have:

Controller:

```
def some_action
    { do some things here }
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end
```

View:

**some_action.js.erb**

```
$('#messages').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'flash_message') %>");

<% if @error == "True" %>
$('#flash').removeClass().addClass( "error" ).html('<%= escape_javascript(@message) %>');
<% else %>
$('#flash').removeClass().addClass( "success" ).html('<%= escape_javascript(@message) %>');
<% end %>
```

Would rather have one action in the controller to control all messages when no other changes are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can abstract that functionality into instance methods, something like this

```
def ajax_success(message)
  @message = message
  render 'ajax/success'
end

def ajax_failure(message)
  @message = message
  render 'ajax/failure'
end
```

Then in your controller

```
def update
  if (successful)
    ajax_success
  else
    ajax_failure
  end
end
```

You can either define these in your `ApplicationController`, or in a module that is included in any controllers where you wish to use them.

There are some issues here when you wish to have actions that respond to multiple content types, but for actions that should only respond to `.js` this should be fine.

Also, I think the standard practice for AJAX responses like this would be to return a JSON message, and then have some javascript function that could decode it and transform the page appropriately.